# 8 speed chainring with single speed 1/8" chain

Tags: chain, chainring, compatibility

Can I use a chainring designed for 6/7/8 speed with a single speed, 1/8" chain?

The rear wheel only has a single cog - no derailleurs.

Comment: Does your rear wheel have one cog or multiples?  Cos 1/8" chain does not work in a derailleur.

Comment: The rear wheel only has a cog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a 6/7/8 speed chainring on a single-speed or internally geared bike I think that will be fine.

You can't use a 1/8" chain with a front or rear derailleur obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use a 1/8" chain on a 7 speed freewheel. I'm running one right now on an electric folding 20x4 fat bike. It will work. I put a larger 60 tooth chain ring on front so I could more easily keep up pedalling at 20 to 28 mph (32-48 km/h).

I changed out the crank arms and had to use 2 chains put together to make it long enough due to the large chain ring, but yes a 1/8" chain Will work on a 7 speed freewheel and derailleur.

Comment: Welcome to SE - this is interesting, but doesn't answer OP's question which was about a singlespeed chain on a chainring intended for 8 speed, so the front end of the chain run, not the rear.  You appear to know your stuff, so have a go at answering some other questions too.